Tomcat NIO(non-blocking) Connector Threads Getting Blocked
I am using Jersey web framework with Scala language for one of their services.
This service is using NIO(non-blocking IO) connector with Tomcat to handle requests asynchronously. There are 10 connector threads specified for NIO connector.
Expected: My expectation is, connector thread handles multiple requests and doesn't block on request when it's doing(IO, calling dependent service etc). Request processing is using separate execution context(Global Execution Context provided by Scala).
Actual: I ran an experiment by introducing a Thread.sleep/calling another loacl web server API with a sleep in a request processing so see if the connector thread moves on to handle next request however we noticed otherwise where connector thread keeps waiting for request to get completed, despite request processing is processed on a separate execution context and using a different thread.
Is there are any gaps in my understanding for using NIO connector? Basically why connector thread is waiting for request completion and not serving other requests?
Thanks
Reference code snippet:
def ping(request: HttpServletRequest, asyncResponse: AsyncResponse): Unit = {
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = CustomExecutionContext.executionContext
  println("This thread is parked until following future is completed")
  Future {
    println("This future is being executed on dedicated execution context")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    asyncResponse.resume(HttpResponses.ok)
  }(ec)
}


I think you need to use the async resources

I am using Async resources, will update question with code snippet.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/non-blocking-thread-sleep-on-jvm/
